# como relacionar punteros a char con Strings

Tags: c, string, punteros

Buenas tardes necesito algún tipo de ayuda que me acerque a mi solución, en C cuando se ejecuta por consola y se incluyen archivos estos se declaran en la sentencia del main con un puntero a punteros de char (matriz de Strings) pero luego necesito guardar esos valores en variables tipo char[] o char * mediante una funcion para lograr modularidad y no puedo. Adjunto parte de mi codigo

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
char *archivo1,*archivo2;
argc=3;
nombreArchivos(cant,argv,archivo1,archivo2);// no pongo ampersand al ser cadenas 
}

void nombreArchivos(int cant, char **argv, char *a1, char* a2)
{
*a1 = argv[1];
*a2 = argv[2];
}
```

pero al volver al main pierdo los valores. muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que esto le puede dar una idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15168795/8933039

Comment: @J.Rodríguez eso lo entiendo, pero no puedo hacer la modificacion mediante la funcioon, igualmente te agradezco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si pretendes que una función cambie los valores de algo que ha recibido como parámetro, deberás pasar siempre un puntero a ese parámetro.

En tu caso, pretendes que `archivo1` y `archivo2` sean modificados, por tanto la llamada a la función ha de pasar la dirección de esas variables, es decir, `&archivo1`, `&archivo2`. Poco importa que esas variables sean punteros o no, si quieres cambiarles el valor (en el caso del puntero quieres cambiar a dónde apuntan), has de pasar su dirección.

Esto te obliga a cambiar la declaración de esos parámetros, ya que `a1` y `a2` no son ya punteros a carácter, sino punteros a punteros (puesto que recibirán la dirección de un puntero).

Lo siguiente es un ejemplo que funciona (no entiendo, por cierto, el papel del parámetro `cant`, ni por qué cambias de valor a `argc`, por lo que he corregido esa parte).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void nombreArchivos(int cant, char **argv, char **a1, char **a2)
{
    *a1 = argv[1];
    *a2 = argv[2];
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *archivo1,*archivo2;
    int cant=3;   // ??
    nombreArchivos(cant,argv,&archivo1,&archivo2);
    printf("archivo1=%s\n", archivo1);
    printf("archivo2=%s\n", archivo2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me has salvado la vida. =)